# Psycopg2-Python: Syntax issue with Update

Tags: python, psycopg2

My code looks like this:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=monty user=postgres host=localhost password=****")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM binance.zrxeth_aggregated FETCH first 1 rows only;")
row = cur.fetchone()
print(row[0])
    datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 3, 16, 27, 29, 198000)
print(row[1])
buy
```

What I am trying to do now is to update the column last_level_fully_taken of my table:

```
lastLevelFullyTaken = true
cur.execute("UPDATE binance.zrxeth_aggregated SET last_level_fully_taken = lastLevelFullyTaken WHERE timestamp = row[0] AND side = row[1];")
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

I get the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: column "row" does not exist
```

I have some difficulties with the syntax, can somebody help me? Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be using the postgres user for regular (non-admin) usage.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, can you explain why then?

Comment: @ThiefMaster, there is no point to comment the post if you don't explain

Comment: @Viktor.w if below answer solves your problem accept it as answer. thanks

Comment: @Viktor.w same reason why you don't use root (or "Administrator" on Windows) for your daily work. These users have basically unlimited privileges over the system (in case of postgres, over the database) and a typical application does not need such privileges.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try below query:

```
query = "UPDATE binance.zrxeth_aggregated SET last_level_fully_taken = lastLevelFullyTaken WHERE timestamp = %s AND side = %s;"
params = (row[0], row[1])
cur.execute(query, params)
```

this should work

Comment: NEVER use `%` or `.format()` to interpolate data into queries.

Comment: @ThiefMaster can you explain it with the example?

Comment: updated answer as per [doc](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters)